# How do I build openssh from source?

Tags: compiling, openssh

I try to install OpenSSH

```
./configure
checking for openssl/opensslv.h... no
configure: error: *** OpenSSL headers missing
```

any idea?

Comment: As jamespo points out, are you sure you want to build it from source? Openssh is quite a critical attack vector if any exploits should be found, so it would be best to use the repositories so you get security updates.

Answer (score 7):

I would install the openssh server package if you have a choice `apt-get install openssh-server`. However if you want to compile from source install openssl first.

Either [from source](http://www.openssl.org/source/) or from the package: `apt-get install libssl-dev openssl`

Answer (score 2):

To install dependencies needed to build a given package, you can use apt-get's **build-dep** option, e.g., `apt-get build-dep openssh` or `apt-get build-dep openssh-server` if you are trying to build the server.

Answer (score 2):

*tl;dr download, unpack, configure, build, install*

#### basic build + install steps

Using version `9.0p1` as an example:

```
wget https://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-9.0p1.tar.gz
tar -xvf openssh-9.0p1.tar.gz
cd openssh-9.0p1
./configure
make
make install
```

##### portable release

Make sure to download the [*Portable Release* source code](https://www.openssh.com/portable.html) (unless running OpenBSD OS).

##### gpg verify

Optionally, verify the download *before* the `tar` command:

```
wget https://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/RELEASE_KEY.asc
gpg --import RELEASE_KEY.asc
wget https://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-9.0p1.tar.gz.asc
gpg --verbose --verify openssh-9.0p1.tar.gz.asc
```

##### build dependencies

If there is a missing header or library during the `./configure` command, you can view the dependencies for the built-in OpenSSH using `apt`

```
apt show openssh-server
```

The packages listed under `Depends:` will *most likely* be adequate for building the downloaded OpenSSH `.tar`.
Install the needed dependencies for building using `apt install`.

A few extra packages I installed on my Debian 10 system:

```
apt install \
  libssl-dev \
  gcc g++ gdb cpp \
  make cmake \
  libtool \
  libc6 \
  autoconf automake pkg-config \
  build-essential \
  gettext
```

---

I wrote [a full step-by-step write-up for installing the latest OpenSSH](https://gist.github.com/jtmoon79/745e6df63dd14b9f2d17a662179e953a).

Answer (score 1):

It's likely you are missing the development headers for openssl. Try installing "openssl-devel".

Comment: @tijybba Can you remove your duplicate comment?