# Install OpenSSh from source on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ssh, openssh

i want to install openssh from source on Ubuntu.
i downloaded the source

1. ./configure
2. make
3. sudo make install

but with this last command, i get the following error:

```
(cd openbsd-compat && make)
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pc/Desktop/openssh-7.6p1/openbsd-compat'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pc/Desktop/openssh-7.6p1/openbsd-compat'
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/bin
make: execvp: ./mkinstalldirs: Permission denied
Makefile:313: recipe for target 'install-files' failed
make: [install-files] Error 127
```

What can i do please to fix this error ? i can't find a solution !

Comment: I'd say the `Permission denied` message indicates you didn't use `sudo` to run `./mkinstalldirs`.

Comment: ./mkinstalldirs !!! when should use this cmd please ?

Comment: Oh. I thought you ran it on yourself. But it is part of the `Makefile`. Sorry. My fault. Given your other comment (`./configure --prefix=/usr/local ...`) I suggest running `make` with `sudo`, i.e. `sudo make`. When you want to install to `/usr/local` then you need `sudo` permissions.

Comment: First, thank u so much for answering me sir.
i tried to use this two cmd .. but i always get the same error with : sudo make install !!!? what should i do please ?

Comment: If you have so many problems compiling and installing openssh from source, why don't you just install the binary package? Do you have special requirements? See [How do I build openssh from source?](https://askubuntu.com/q/33754/504066).

Comment: yes .. i want to edit one the used protocol .. so i need to install it using the code source .. is there any suggestion sir ?

Comment: see  https://askubuntu.com/questions/344506/permission-denied-when-running-make-install

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when compiling, and it depends on how the developer builds his Makefile, he has had to specify the output directory, so he does not give me the errors.

```
./configure --prefix = /path_for_build
```

Comment: i tried to tape this cmd:
 ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --sysconfdir=/etc/ssh --with-md5-passwords
but i always get the same error !